# OpenFeint automatically detected I denied OpenFeint in my iPhone app

Tags: iphone, openfeint

After I launch OpenFeint with function initializeWithProductKey, I checked the user approval status by calling the function [OpenFeint hasUserApprovedFeint]. The function always returned false value.

The settings Dictionary is as follow:

```
NSDictionary* settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight], OpenFeintSettingDashboardOrientation,
                                  @"PA", OpenFeintSettingShortDisplayName, 
                                  [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], OpenFeintSettingEnablePushNotifications,
                                  nil];
```

The App is already a clean build, with a clean simulator (with content & settings reset).

[OpenFeint launchDashboard] has also no response.

In debug console, it reports the version:

> Using OpenFeint version
>   1182010.https://api.openfeint.com/

Anybody has the same issue? How to solve?